# How to create local notification with an end date

Tags: react-native, uilocalnotification

I need to do local notification with an end date. I have taken look at https://wix.github.io/react-native-notifications/docs/localNotifications/ and https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification but cannot find an example of how it would work. I want a notification to have start and end date with an interval

Comment: What do you mean when you say it should have an end date? Do you want the notification cancelled if the end date has passed?

Comment: Yes, I want notification to stop at end date

Answer (score 0):

This is answer is geared towards the second library you mentioned: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification.

For setting the start date for when a notification should occur we have
the `localNotificationSchedule` method described in the documentation here: https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#scheduled-notifications.

For example:

```
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';

PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
  id: "1",
  message: "My Notification Message", // (required)
  date: new Date(Date.now() + 60 * 1000), // in 60 secs
  // other props...
});
```

So whatever date object you pass to the `date` property will be the moment the notification is triggered.

Note that `autoCancel` by default has the value of `true` so after the notification is delivered the notification will be canceled anyway. So it's better not to handle the end date as it's already handled for you.

---

If you still want to cancel it anyway you can add `autoCancel: true` to the example above and cancel the notification like this:

```
PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({id: '1'});
```

So if you want to control the end date, an idea could be to first trigger your push notification and directly after call `cancelLocalNotifications` inside `setTimeout`. Then you could control when the notifications starts and when it is canceled.

If you want to have a way to do this in the background you can look into a background task library like https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch.